# Using Single Page Application in Umbraco CMS

Tags: umbraco, single-page-application, umbraco7

I know we can use ASP.NET MVC or Web Form in Umbraco CMS but is it Possible to use Single Page Application(SPA) in Umbraco CMS?
If yes, How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean have a SPA published from Umbraco as a content managed page or as a custom section within the CMS backoffice?

Comment: Please describe it in both cases.

Comment: Hmm, you may need to be a bit more specific in your question then as it could be quite a large topic. What exactly have you tried and can't do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this [post](http://www.nibble.be/?p=224) which contains the use of Umbraco as datasource for SPA.

Comment: The link is not working any more, so the answer is useless.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I've used in the past could be to expose the underlying Umbraco data as a web service by creating a Web Api controller, as described in the [documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/).

You may then build an SPA application that consumes this RESTful web service. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) for an example.